# how to use json_encode to fetch data from database

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I Have 2 table that I want to join them and fetch some data like this
I have one student with multiple grade

```
   {
    "student": {
    "studentID": "2",
    "Name": "s1",
    "age": " 12",
    "grade": [
    {
      "GradeID": "2"
    },{
      "GradeID": "3"
    }
]
  }
```

I fetch this data from two query in a function in my model and then use json_encode in my controller for my output
but I have this

```
{
  "student": {
    "studentID": "2",
    "Name": "s1",
    "age": " 12"
},
    "grade": [
    {
      "GradeID": "2"
    },{
      "GradeID": "3"
    }
]
  }
```

and now I don't know how to use json_encode for the first format.
thanks

```
my model(student):
 function get_student_id($id)
    {
        $student['student']=
            $this->db->select('tbl_student.*')
                 ->from('tbl_student')
                 ->where('tbl_student.SID',$id)
                 ->get()->row();

        $student['grade']=
            $this->db->select('tbl_grade.GradeID')
                ->from('tbl_grade')
                ->join('tbl_sudent','tbl_grade.StudentID=tbl_sudent.SID')
                ->where('tbl_student.SID',$id)
                ->get()->result();



        return $student;
}
```

my controller:

```
public function get_student_id()
    {

        $id = $input['one'];
        $this->load->model('student');
        $temp=$this->student->get_student_id($id);
        $output= json_encode($temp);

        die($output);

    }
```

Comment: where is your CODE ???

Comment: can you share your query code. I think single query can do all your task  using Jonis

Comment: Simply use json_encode() function it will return json format data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to structure the array you're returning from the model correctly. You're putting everything inside two subarrays called student and grade, which are inside the outer array student. Try this:

```
my model(student):
 function get_student_id($id)
    {
        $student=
            $this->db->select('tbl_student.*')
                 ->from('tbl_student')
                 ->where('tbl_student.SID',$id)
                 ->get()->row();

        $student['grade']=
            $this->db->select('tbl_grade.GradeID')
                ->from('tbl_grade')
                ->join('tbl_sudent','tbl_grade.StudentID=tbl_sudent.SID')
                ->where('tbl_student.SID',$id)
                ->get()->result();



        return $student;
}
```

I'm not totally certain you want to call `get->row()` on the first query, if that doesn't work try `get->row_array()`